# Radius of convergence for matrix exponential

Tags: matrices, power-series, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential, matrix-analysis

In the context of systems of linear ODE with constant coefficients, my lecture notes on ODE mention that the matrix exponential $e^{tA}$ has an infinite radius of convergence. This shows up in a proof that $e^{tA}$ is a fundamental matrix of $y'(t)=Ay(t)$, where the derivative of a matrix-valued function can be defined component-wise.

The matrix exponential function is defined by the series

$exp(A):=e^A:=\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{A^n}{n!}$.

Now I know that in the case of the power series in $\mathbb{C}$ we define the radius of convergence of a power series $\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n z^n$ as

$R:=\sup \{r \geq0:(c_n r^n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \text{ is a bounded sequence}\}$

where bounded means that $|c_n r^n| \leq M$ for some $M>0$.

How can we generalize this to matrix power series like the matrix exponential? In general, it does not make sense to take the supremum over a set of matrices. But if we have a power series where $z$ is still a complex number, and only the coefficients can be matrices, then we could use the same definition as before

$R:=\sup \{r \geq0:(C_n r^n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \text{ is a bounded sequence}\}$

where $C_n$ are matrices and bounded then means that $\|C_n r^n\|| \leq M$ for some $C$.

It follows that each component of the power series has the same radius of convergence as the matrix series.

So we can differentiate term-wise in each component to obtain the derivative of the matrix exponential.

Is this a common definition? I could not find any source that gives a general definition.

Thanks for any help and suggestions!

Comment: Usually we show that the series converges absolutely (for any matrix A) with respect to the _operator norm_ on the space of nxn matrices. That’s a convenient norm because it exists for bounded linear operators on any Banach space (not only finite-dimensional ones) and because it is a sub-multiplicative norm.

Comment: @shalop Thanks for your comment. Yes, my notes contain a proof of that kind and it is clear to me. I think one could also simply state that every component series is convergent by the properties of the operator norm. I am not sure if my post does not make it clear enough, but I am simply trying to understand how we would define the radius of convergence for the matrix exponential $e^{tA}$. I couldn't really find a source that so far. My notes mention it in a proof, but do not give a definition for the case of a power series $\sum C_k t^n$ where $C_k$ are matrices and $t \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @shalopI guess maybe the main problem is my particular definition of the radius of convergence. Wikipedia simply defines it in terms of values at which the absolute value of the series converges (see edit), so we can replace this by the operator norm in my case. Is this what you were referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can actually keep the same definition for matrix power series since it is in terms of real sequences $(c_n r^n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ only, i.e $r \geq 0$ is a non-negative real number.

For complex series we then have:

Theorem: Let the power series $P(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n z^n$ have radius of convergence $R$. Then

$(i)$ $P(z)$ diverges for all $z$ with $\lvert z \rvert >R$.

$(ii)$ For each $0<r<R$, the series $P(z)$ converges uniformly on $\bar{B}_r(0)=\{z \in \mathbb{C}:\lvert z \rvert \leq r\}$

$(iii)$ $P(z)$ converges absolutely for $z \in B_R(0)=\{z \in \mathbb{C}:\lvert z \rvert <R\}$

A similar statement follows for matrix power series by replacing the absolute value by the matrix norm (see [here](http://reh.math.uni-duesseldorf.de/%7Egruenroc/AnaII_HP/slides/Slides(AnaII1.41).pdf)).

Answer (score 3):

You are correct to observe that we need some suitable function from matrices to real numbers to define convergence. This is called a [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Equivalence). Unfortunately for a vector space (and the set of matrices here can be seen as a vector space) there is more than one norm. Fortunately, there is a theorem that says on a finite dimensional vector space all norms are equivalent (see also the wikipedia article). Here this means that all norms will give us the same definition of convergence.

One possible norm for matrices is the sum of the absolute values of the eigenvalues of the matrix. Using this norm (maybe there is a more convenient choice of norm) one can show that the radius of convergence of the exponential series is indeed infinite.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I am familiar with norms and their equivalence on finite-dimensional spaces. My problem is simply that my lecture notes on real analysis only define the radius of convergence for complex series and my lecture notes on ODE do not define it for a matrix power series.

Comment: @DerivativesGuy A sequence of matrices converges if their norm converges.

Answer (score 1):

Write $$A\le aU$$ where $a$ is the largest element of $A$ and $U$ is a $d\times d$ matrix of all ones. The comparison is made element-wise, ignoring the signs.

Then

$$A^n\le(aU)^n= d^{n-1}a^nU$$ and

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{A^n}{n!}\le\frac{e^{da}}dU=:MU.$$